# VBoxManage: write to filesystem

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

How can I write a file to a running virtual os? I'd like to write to the `hosts` file of the guest OS in order to set some aliases, is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make targeted folder available several protocols:

- samba
- ftp
- nfs
- ssh
- etc ...

as hosts file is in /etc (or not - you don't specify OS) I suggest SSH as most proper solution.